# How to use `tar` command to package helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, tar

I had a helm chart named `test` and wanted to package it.
When i used command `helm package ./test` and `helm install test test-0.1.0.tgz` command, it succeeded.
But when i used `tar zcf test.tgz ./test` and `helm install test test.tgz`, it failed.
I used `tar zxvf`  to untar `test-0.1.0.tgz` and `test.tgz`, i found that they were the same by command `diff`.
How to use `tar` to package helm chart?

Comment: helm version:"v3.2.4"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you use the helm package command?

Comment: When you say "it failed", what happened?

Comment: Because I don't want to introduce helm for simplify dependency. it's possible to package without helm? @CaioT

Comment: it showed `Error: validation: chart.metadata is required` when i deployed the tar file but there was a Chart.yaml in my package, when i used `helm package` to package  it, i can deployed success @DavidMaze

Comment: Hello @JingWang and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit your question and show examples of what are you trying and what to achieve? Also, please show us your helm charts.

Answer (score 0):

Don't! You want to package your chart by using `helm package` which will create the tar file you want. If you package it manually it won't be read correctly by helm. I think that's the issue you're seeing.

You need to let helm package does more than just create the tar file, so creating the tar is necessary but not sufficient to be used by helm later.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the content of the two tars:

the one you get with `helm package` organizes the whole chart under a folder named after the chart name (eg: `/myChart`).

The package created with your command instead will contain a root folder named `.` (the actual chart will be under `/./test` in your case). That's because of how `tar` behaves with relative paths (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144090/create-a-tar-archive-of-the-current-directory-without-preceding-period) for a dedicated question).

If you really want to bypass Helm, you can run `tar zcf test.tgz test` (no `./`) or apply a transformation with `tar --xform s:'./':: -zcf test.tgz ./test`